# Check if a rule is passed in Cart rules

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I can see the rules applied to a cart with

```
CheckoutCartPageLoadedEvent

$event->getPage()->getCart()->getRuleIds()
```

but how can I know if a certain rule passed or not? For what I understand the RuleIds array contains all the rules evaulated, but I can't see if they are passed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ruleIds` list properties retrieved from either the current `Context` object or the current `Cart` object should only contain the ids of `rule` entities that evaluated to `true`. If an id is included, the rule's conditions were met, otherwise they weren't.